# hibernate SchemaExport tool fails to export schema and creates strange sql queries that even fails on sql command line utility

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am creating a schema manually through another utility and is successful.

I am creating a session factory elsewhere using the config xml .

When I try and run Schema export it gives a weird error in the logs such as

```
13:18:33,932 ERROR SchemaExport:386 - Unsuccessful: create table entitydef (id bigint not    null auto_increment unique, hbmfile LONGTEXT, isExported tinyint not null, name varchar(50), schemaId bigint, typeId bigint, primary key (id)) type=InnoDB
```

I tried running the query on sql workbench and it works when I remove the type=InnoDB part.

What is wrong out here ? I have removed the rest pojo definitions for brevity.

I have created a hibernate.cfg.xml containing the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">**********</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev_org_appops_entitystore_0_0_1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="default_entity_mode">POJO</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>


    <!-- this is c3p0 configuration -->
    <property name="org.hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5</property>

    <!--ehcache configuration-->

    <mapping class="org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.dao.domain.Entitydef"/>
    <mapping class="org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.dao.domain.Property"/>
    <mapping class="org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.dao.domain.Propertydef"/>
    <mapping class="org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.dao.domain.Schemadef"/>
    <mapping class="org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.dao.domain.Types"/>
    <mapping class="org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.dao.domain.QueryDef"/>
    <mapping class="org.appops.entityStore.hibernate.dao.domain.QueryParamType"/>

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have annotated pojo like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entitydef")
public class Entitydef implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Long typeId;
private Long schemaId;
private String hbmfile;
private byte isExported;

public Entitydef() {
}

public Entitydef(final byte isExported) {
    this.isExported = isExported;
}

public Entitydef(final String name, final Long typeId, final Long schemaId, final String hbmfile,
        final byte isExported) {
    this.name = name;
    this.typeId = typeId;
    this.schemaId = schemaId;
    this.hbmfile = hbmfile;
    this.isExported = isExported;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "name", length = 50)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "typeId")
public Long getTypeId() {
    return this.typeId;
}

public void setTypeId(final Long typeId) {
    this.typeId = typeId;
}

@Column(name = "schemaId")
public Long getSchemaId() {
    return this.schemaId;
}

public void setSchemaId(final Long schemaId) {
    this.schemaId = schemaId;
}

@Column(name = "hbmfile", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
public String getHbmfile() {
    return this.hbmfile;
}

public void setHbmfile(final String hbmfile) {
    this.hbmfile = hbmfile;
}

@Column(name = "isExported", nullable = false)
public byte getIsExported() {
    return this.isExported;
}

public void setIsExported(final byte isExported) {
    this.isExported = isExported;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

I needed to use

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
```

instead of

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
```

since MySql in use is above 5.0